# Django(DRF) Null field in client address

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to save client details .
below is models.py:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    street_address_line_1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    street_address_line_2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    zip = models.IntegerField()   
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)   



class Client(models.Model):
    primary_contact_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    primary_contact_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    primary_contact_email = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    primary_contact_phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    primary_contact_phone_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    secondary_contact_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    secondary_contact_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    secondary_contact_email = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    secondary_contact_phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    secondary_contact_phone_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    client_address = models.ForeignKey(Address,related_name="client_address",on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=False)
    
   
    def __str__(self):
        return self.primary_contact_email
```

and views.py:

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def createClientView(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        serializer = ClientSerializer(data=request.data, many=False)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        error = Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        return error
```

and serializers.py:

```
class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = [
            "street_address_line_1",
            "street_address_line_2",
            "city",
            "state",
            "zip",
            "country",
        ]


class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    address = AddressSerializer(source="addresss",read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = [
            "primary_contact_first_name",
            "primary_contact_last_name",
            "primary_contact_email",
            "primary_contact_phone_number",
            "primary_contact_phone_type",
            "secondary_contact_first_name",
            "secondary_contact_last_name",
            "secondary_contact_email",
            "secondary_contact_phone_number",
            "secondary_contact_phone_type",
            "address",
        ]
        def create(self,validated_data):
            address_data=validated_data.pop("address")
            client=Client.objects.create(**validated_data)
            Address.objects.create(client=client,**address_data)
            return client
```

example data to post:

```
{
    "primary_contact_first_name": "iliyas",
    "primary_contact_last_name": "shaik",
    "primary_contact_email": "a@a.com",
    "primary_contact_phone_number": "9185213654",
    "primary_contact_phone_type": "HOme",
    "secondary_contact_first_name": "meraa",
    "secondary_contact_last_name": "shaik",
    "secondary_contact_email": "z@z.com",
    "secondary_contact_phone_number": "8963251470",
    "secondary_contact_phone_type": "Mobile",
    "address": {
        "street_address_line_1": "NTR NAGAR",
        "street_address_line_2": "CHOWRASTA",
        "city": "KURNOOL",
        "state": "ANDHRA",
        "zip": 51896352,
        "country": "INDIA"
    }
}
```

[image]

client_address_id is null when the post request data is serialized and clientaddress_id is foriegn key which should be id of row present in address model table but here no data is being saved ,the address model table is empty.How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `create` the method of `ClientSerializer`

```
class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    address = AddressSerializer(source="addresss")

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = [
            "primary_contact_first_name",
            "primary_contact_last_name",
            "primary_contact_email",
            "primary_contact_phone_number",
            "primary_contact_phone_type",
            "secondary_contact_first_name",
            "secondary_contact_last_name",
            "secondary_contact_email",
            "secondary_contact_phone_number",
            "secondary_contact_phone_type",
            "address",
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        address_data = validated_data['address']
        # Create address instance
        address = Address.objects.create(...)

        # Create client instance
        client = Client.objects.create(...)

        return client
```

Comment: would you please show me an example?it would help me alot.

Comment: overided create method but it's the same.edited question with it.

Comment: I updated my answer. You will get an idea.

Comment: how would I set foreignkey client_address_id field value from client model to the same row where address is being saved using create method?

Comment: Please look at the create method in my answer. Firstly address is created after that client is created. You can easily use the address Id as a foreign key in the client.